# ionic 2/3- not getting response from http get request

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3, angular-httpclient

I'm creating an ionic 2 app. For fetching response, I use `HttpClient` over `Http`
Created a provider using `ionic generate provider JobServicesProvider`

Provider looks like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface DataResponse {
  userId: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class JobServicesProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello JobServicesProvider Provider');
  }

  fetchJSONData() {
    return this.http.get<DataResponse>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').subscribe(data => {
    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        } else {
          console.log('Server-side error occured.');
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling fetchJSONData() from my component for getting the data. Injected the provider properly.

Here's the code:

```
import { JobServicesProvider } from './../../providers/job-services/job-services';
import { JobDetailsMainPage } from './../job-details-main-page/job-details-main-page';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-jobs-page',
  templateUrl: 'new-jobs-page.html',
})
export class NewJobsPage {
  newJobs: any;

  constructor(private jobService: JobServicesProvider) {
    this.toFetchJos();
  }

  toFetchJos(){
    this.newJobs = this.jobService.fetchNewJobs();
    console.log(this.newJobs);
  }
}
```

I console.log() the response I got from provider, I'm getting a response but it does not have the result in JSON format. How can I get the data in JSON format?

Here's a screenshot of the response I'm getting. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Note: When I console the data in provider function, I get it the result in JSON format but I'm not getting the same when I console it in the component function

Comment: Thats because you are subscribing inside of your service method, and returning the subscription object. Please check https://angular.io/guide/http Notice that `subscribe` is called at component level.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I modified your code a little but. Try this and let me know if it does not work.

You were subscribing inside of your service method, and returning the subscription object

Modify the provider to something like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class JobServicesProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello JobServicesProvider Provider');
  }

  fetchJSONData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
   }
}
```

and your component to the code given below

```
import { JobServicesProvider } from './../../providers/job-services/job-services';
import { JobDetailsMainPage } from './../job-details-main-page/job-details-main-page';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-jobs-page',
  templateUrl: 'new-jobs-page.html',
})
export class NewJobsPage {
  newJobs: any;

  constructor(private jobService: JobServicesProvider) {
    this.toFetchJos();
  }

  toFetchJos() {
    this.jobService.fetchJSONData()
      .then(data => {
        this.newJobs = data;
        console.log(this.newJobs);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO is totally unnecessary to wrap the HTTP observable in a promise

Comment: Is it a bad practice to do like that? So what's your suggestion? Can you modify the code to make it look like what you suggested? @Jota.Toledo

Comment: @Annabelle added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Currently your service method signature is the following:

```
fetchJSONData(): Subscription;
```

As you are subscribing to the observable returned by http.get and returning the subscription object. Thats why console.log is printing that "weird" object at component level.

The signature that you want is:

```
fetchJSONData(): Observable<DataResponse[]>;
```

This can be archived by changing your code to the following:

```
fetchJSONData(): Observable<DataResponse[]> {
    return this.http.get<DataResponse[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/');
  }
```

Notice that the return type is now an observable that emits array instances, as your endpoint returns an array.

Now considering that your service returns a ***cold observable***, you need call `subscribe` on the observable instance for the HTTP request to be executed:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-jobs-page',
  templateUrl: 'new-jobs-page.html',
})
export class NewJobsPage {
  jobs: DataResponse[] = [];
  // variable initialized as empty array to avoid NULL handling

  constructor(private jobService: JobServicesProvider) {
    this.toFetchJobs();
  }

  toFetchJos(){
    this.jobService.fetchNewJobs().subscribe(jobs => this.jobs = jobs);
  }
}
```

Further explanations to the basics of the `HttpClient` API can be found in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)